# R server broadcasting data

Tags: r, sockets, server, daemon

I'm trying to write the daemon in R such as it would be broadcasting the data to some data pipe and any peer connected to this pipe would get the **last** value transmitted. I've changed the server code from [here](http://blog.corynissen.com/2013/05/using-r-to-communicate-via-socket.html), so my server side looks:

```
server <- function(){
  writeLines("Listening...")
  con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 6011, blocking=TRUE,
                          server=TRUE, open="r+")
  while(TRUE){
    broadcast_msg <- as.character(Sys.time())
    writeLines(broadcast_msg, con) 
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
  close(con)
}
server()
```

On client side i just connect and read the lines:

```
con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 6011, blocking=TRUE, server=FALSE, open="r+")
server_resp_update <- readLines(con, 1)
server_resp_update <- readLines(con, 1)
server_resp_update <- readLines(con, 1)
```

The code above has two problems:

1. Daemon waits for the peer to connect. However i want it to broadcast the data in any case.
2. When i connect and read the data with client several times i get the first lines sent in the beginning after the connection, but not the last up-to-date value.

There was similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715082/just-get-one-last-value-from-socket) in Python and the answer was to inverse the problem doing:

1. Wait for a connection
2. Give a message
3. go to step 1

In my case *2. Give a message* involves heavy calculation and i dont want to do them for every peer's request - i want the daemon to do them once a sec for everyone who needs the message.

I did managed to get this scheme work using a txt file, i.e. the daemon re-writes a new value in the file every second and the client reads the file when it needs to do so. No waiting for peer's involved. However writing/reading file is not as fast as socket connection can be.